# Optional dependencies in Chocolatey package

Tags: powershell, nuget, chocolatey

I'm writing a package to install a programming tool, a tool which users may use in addition to their preferred IDE, compiler, etc.

I want to parametrize the package install in a way that the user can say: *"Hey, install the tool, with Visual Studio 12 and MinGW"*. If that's the case, then both Visual Studio 12 and MinGW packages will be added as dependencies, so they are installed before my tool.

The nuspec reference says nothing about optional dependencies. **Is there a way to specify those, and enable them via the `chocolateyInstall.ps1` script depending on user input?**

Comment: Are you trying to integrate your tool with these other packages? A user can just say `choco install visualstudio2012ultimate  mingw yourpackage` if they want those other packages installed as well. There are [package parameters](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/How-To-Parse-PackageParameters-Argument) in chocolatey.

Comment: Visual Studio 12? Real version number (and thus Visual Studio 2013)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folks usually create two packages, one with the core bits and required dependencies and a second meta package that takes a dependency on the tool and the other items (optional dependencies).

Optional dependencies is something that has come up in discussions in the past, and it is something we are looking at on the roadmap.